# serial number for faq displayed from admin

Tags: php

I am using the following code for display questions and answers from admin.

```
<?php
    $select_faq = "Select `intFaqid`, `varQuestion`,`varAnswer` FROM `tbl_faq`";
    $selectfaq_result = mysql_query($select_faq);
    $select_faqnum = mysql_num_rows($selectfaq_result);

    if($selectfaq_result > 0)
    {
        while($fetch_faq = mysql_fetch_array($selectfaq_result))
        {

        $faqid = $fetch_faq['intFaqid'];
        $fquestion = strip_tags(ucfirst(stripslashes(nl2br($fetch_faq['varQuestion']))));
        $fanswer = strip_tags(ucfirst(stripslashes(nl2br($fetch_faq['varAnswer']))));
        ?>

        <h3><?php echo $fquestion; ?></h3>
        <p><?php echo $fanswer; ?></p>




    <?php   
        }
    }
  ?>
```

I need to display the question number before the question. I used the following code for display the question number.

```
<?php
  $questionno = 1;
    $numberlimit = $select_faqnum;
    while($questionno<=$numberlimit)
    {
        echo $questionno;
        $questionno++;

    }
  ?>
```

But i doesn't know how to display the question number before the question by combining both the codes. I need the output should display the question with question number. How can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Am I missing something?  I am not sure why you would make it so complex.

Since your recordset is already determining the number of rows, why not just do this:

```
   if($selectfaq_result > 0)
    {

//initialise your variable
$question_number = 0;

    while($fetch_faq = mysql_fetch_array($selectfaq_result))
    { 

//increment your variable
$question_number++;

        $faqid = $fetch_faq['intFaqid'];
        $fquestion = strip_tags(ucfirst(stripslashes(nl2br($fetch_faq['varQuestion']))));
        $fanswer = strip_tags(ucfirst(stripslashes(nl2br($fetch_faq['varAnswer']))));
        ?>

   //concatenate the string to include the variable.  
   //Don't forget to leave a space after it so it looks pretty
    <h3><?php echo $question_number . ": " . $fquestion; ?></h3>

    <p><?php echo $fanswer; ?></p>

<?php   
    }
```

Your line number will finish when you run out of records

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    $select_faq = "Select `intFaqid`, `varQuestion`,`varAnswer` FROM `tbl_faq`";
    $selectfaq_result = mysql_query($select_faq);
    $select_faqnum = mysql_num_rows($selectfaq_result);

    if($select_faqnum > 0)
    {
        $question_number = 0;
        while($fetch_faq = mysql_fetch_array($selectfaq_result))
        {
            $question_number++;
            $faqid = $fetch_faq['intFaqid'];
            $fquestion = strip_tags(ucfirst(stripslashes(nl2br($fetch_faq['varQuestion']))));
            $fanswer = strip_tags(ucfirst(stripslashes(nl2br($fetch_faq['varAnswer']))));
            ?>
            <h3><?php echo "$question_number. $fquestion"; ?></h3>
            <p><?php echo $fanswer; ?></p>
    <?php   
        }
    }
?>
```

is that what you are looking for ?